# Java getting a certain property from the config.properties file that exists more than once

Tags: java, iterator, enumeration, properties-file

I have `config.properties` file that contains names.

Say it looks as such:

```
#Client1 properties
1Client=Client1
1someproperty=someproperty
#Client2 properties
2Client=Client1
2someproperty=someproperty
```

What I am trying to achieve is only getting the client names in a `DefaultListModel` so I can add them to a list. I have tried the following:

```
public static DefaultListModel SetVM() {
    int clientCode = 1;
    DefaultListModel vm_list = new DefaultListModel();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        props.load(fis);
        fis = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        //if (statement to see if props contains clientCode) {
            String vmClient = props.getProperty(DatabaseCode + "CLIENT");
            vm_list.addElement(vmClient);
        //}
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return vm_list;
}
```

I was thinking along the line of `for(Object obj : fis)`, but that is not possible. The other option was using an iterator as discribed [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/UsingEnumerationtoloopthroughProperties.htm).
Though I cannot grasp how to get a certain property.

Comment: So, you want to get all the properties whose key ends with "Client", is that right? Iterate on the entrySet of the props, test if the key of the entry ends with Client, and add the value to the model if it does. You ofcourse must create the inputstream **before** loading the properties from it.

Comment: Yes correct. This helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Using Properties entrySet which gives you the key and value for each property.

```
@Test
public void testClient () throws IOException {

    DefaultListModel<String> vm_list = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    fis = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
    props.load(fis);
    for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : props.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Entry key:" + entry.getKey() + " value:" + entry.getValue());
        String key = (String)entry.getKey();
        if (key.endsWith("Client")) {
            vm_list.addElement(key); // maybe want to add entry.getValue() instead
        }
    }
    // return vm_list;      
}
```

Comment: This works as I want. I understand how getting the key of the value is better than looking for just the String. It makes the steps taken a lot clearer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Just used the regex to identify the client property.
Hope this helps.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

    try
    {
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
        for(String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()){
            if(key.matches("(\\d+)Client")){
                //add to arrayList
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I appreciate the time you took to write this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

> Manage with a domain class

```
public class Client {

private String client;
private String someproperty;

// default constructor
// parameterized constructor
// get set methods
}



public static List<Client> SetVM() {

        List<Client> vm_list = new ArrayList<Client>();

        // client codes example
        Integer clientCodes[] = { 1, 2 };

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

            // get the property values
            for (Integer code : clientCodes) {
                vm_list.add(new Client(prop.getProperty(code + "Client"), prop.getProperty(code + "someproperty")));
            }
            return vm_list;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: If I do this I would be making an extra class. In this case I don't see the purpose as I already have the properties file.